# Hyper-V vs KVM for running Ubuntu + Windows

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

I am currently planning to set up a server for virtualisation. It will be running about half Windows 2012 servers and half Ubuntu. Would it be better to use hyper-v or KVM as the hypervisor as I am not sure which would give the best performance.

Comment: I think you be hard pressed to see a performance difference, so I'd go with what you are most familiar with.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted another opinion before I did anything stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself would go with Hyper-V (especially if 3.0) as long as MSFT verifies that your Ubuntu version will run as a VM...

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(v=ws.10).aspx for Hyper-V on W2008[R2] Linux guest compatability
(Cannot find the same sort of article for Hyper-V on 2012, but hopefully there will be one soon)

Comment: well Will I guess we won't know what he's using in this case!

Comment: reason for that being?